# Angular function response in HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I have an Angular component function which returns a string I need to show in my HTML. The function works, but the html tag generates as empty.

Function:

```
getTaskNameById(id: any): string {
  console.log('function start; id = ' + id);
  this.tasks.forEach(e => {
    if (e.idTask === Number(id)) {
      console.log('if statement true; name = ' + e.name);
      return e.name;
    }
  });
  return '';
}
```

HTML:

```
{{ getTaskNameById(form.value.tasks[i]) }}:
```

```
[Console log][1]
[Page look][2]
[Generated HTML][3]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pasl0.png
[2]: https://i.imgur.com/0CKhxLt.png
[3]: https://i.imgur.com/YSkJJrY.png
```

Comment: Can you share a copy in stackbiltz

Comment: I'm sorry about the bad format, the html part should be in a label tag, the page would not allow me to post no matter how I formatted the code

Comment: @AdritaSharma https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2pbass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is empty because it is not possible to return inside of `Array.forEach`.

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
>   is the wrong tool.

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for more information.

You need to change it to a normal `for-loop` or you can use some Array build in functions, like `Array.find`. See following:

```
getTaskNameById(id: any): string {
    console.log('function start; id = ' + id);
    const task = this.tasks.find(t => t.idTask === +id);
    if (task) return task.name;
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Great, happy to help =)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use a method to get the task name because you already have an instant of the taks items when you loop throw the array like this

```
<label *ngFor="let t of tasks; let i = index">
      id {{t.idTask}} , name {{ t.name }}<br>
</label>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnbaqu)

Comment: This was just a demo to showcase the problem, i'm looping through different items in the html hence the need for function. But thank you anyway.